# Insuficient funds, mainnet > 2000$

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

I'm trying to deploy an NFT contract using remix. I've deployed in development, ropsten and now mainnet. The value is approximately $2,200 to deploy the contract. Is this okay or my contract that needs modification? GWEI now: **195 GWEI**

Edit

Imports:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.4/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.4/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Comment: How much was the gas limit and gas used on Ropsten? Do you have the transaction hash from the deployment?

Comment: I gave up using the truffle and used the remix anyway. Contract is already pending, in a while it ends.

Comment: I saw in some posts that using ERC-721 raises the price to generate the contract by more than 2k.

Comment: It is already done, so I can't help much with that. For the next time run some tests on Ganache, Rinkeby or Ropsten (any test network should be the same). Pay attention to gasLimit and gasUsed, also try enabling optimization in the solidity options.